# How do I restyle an Adobe Flex Accordion to include a button in each canvas header?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Here is the sample code for my accordion:

```
<mx:Accordion x="15" y="15" width="230" height="599" styleName="myAccordion">
    <mx:Canvas id="pnlSpotlight" label="SPOTLIGHT" height="100%" width="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
        <mx:VBox width="100%" height="80%" paddingTop="2" paddingBottom="1"  verticalGap="1">
            <mx:Repeater id="rptrSpotlight" dataProvider="{aSpotlight}">            
                <sm:SmallCourseListItem 
                    viewClick="PlayFile(event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem().fileID);"
                    Description="{rptrSpotlight.currentItem.fileDescription}"
                    FileID = "{rptrSpotlight.currentItem.fileID}"   
                    detailsClick="{detailsView.SetFile(event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem().fileID,this)}" 
                    Title="{rptrSpotlight.currentItem.fileTitle}"
                    FileIcon="{iconLibrary.getIcon(rptrSpotlight.currentItem.fileExtension)}" />
            </mx:Repeater>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Accordion>
```

I would like to include a button in each header like so:

[image: wishful" onclick="alert('xss')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I got it working using [FlexLib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/)'s CanvasButtonAccordionHeader.

Comment: Hi Shawn, Would you please share the source code of using FlexLib's CanvasButtonAccordionHeader in your application. I am having a little trouble in finding the way around and the documentation on the page doesn't help much too.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom header renderer, add a button to it and position it manually. Try something like this:

```
<mx:Accordion>
    <mx:headerRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <AccordionHeader xmlns="mx.containers.accordionClasses.*">
                <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[

                import mx.controls.Button;


                private var extraButton : Button;


                override protected function createChildren( ) : void {
                    super.createChildren();

                    if ( extraButton == null ) {
                        extraButton = new Button();

                        addChild(extraButton);
                    }
                }

                override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number ) : void {
                    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                    extraButton.setActualSize(unscaledHeight - 6, unscaledHeight - 6);
                    extraButton.move(unscaledWidth - extraButton.width - 3, (unscaledHeight - extraButton.height)/2);
                }

                ]]>
                </mx:Script>
            </AccordionHeader>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:headerRenderer>

    <mx:HBox label="1"><Label text="Text 1"/></HBox>
    <mx:HBox label="1"><Label text="Text 2"/></HBox>
    <mx:HBox label="1"><Label text="Text 3"/></HBox>
</mx:Accordion>
```